# Flutter Bottom Navigation Bar Should Be Transparent

Tags: flutter, bottomnavigationview

I Want to Remove This White Color from Bottom Navigation.. How can I do this?

[image]

This is My Bottom Navigation Bar Code:

```
class MyNavigation extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyNavigationState createState() => _MyNavigationState();
}

class _MyNavigationState extends State<MyNavigation> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  List<Widget> children = <Widget>[
    MyHomePage(),
    MyWallet(),
    MyNotification(),
    MyProfile(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: children.elementAt(_currentIndex),
      bottomNavigationBar: CustomBottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          CustomBottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icons.home_filled,
            title: "Home",
          ),
          CustomBottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icons.home_filled,
            title: "Directions",
          ),
          CustomBottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icons.settings,
            title: "Settings",
          ),
        ],
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(
            () {
              _currentIndex = index;
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This Dependency I Used :
https://pub.dev/packages/custom_bottom_navigation_bar

Comment: Did you tried backgroundColor: Colors.transparent?

Comment: it's so bad user expirience when selected item looks exactly like FAB...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately somebody has just uploaded the package to pub.dev. The author has decided not to upload the code to GitHub. As you might have already checked the package does not expose a property to make the extra area above icon tiles transparent. You may contact the author and get permissions to edit the code, however it will still involve re-wrting a lot of code. It is best to use an alternative package which is backed by its author.